# How can I change faction?

Tags: neocron

When I created my character I went with "Tangent Technologies" as my faction.

I have now completed the epic quest and got my laser pistol so I want to change my faction.

What do I need to do in order to change to another faction on my character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to change faction, you need at least 50 faction sympathy with the faction you wish to change to and 300000 credits as a fee. Once you've got both of these, simply speak to a Human Resources Manager for the faction you wish to change to, these are usually located within the faction headquarters for the faction.

In order to get 50 faction sympathy, you can do either of the following;

- Run missions (recycle missions are the easiest to do quickly, but any mission will grant faction sympathy)
- Kill players who are members of a faction that is an enemy of the faction you wish to change to

It is worth noting that even with 50 faction sympathy, if the faction you're trying to change to is hostile to your current faction the guards will still attack you. There is a minor grace period for this so it is possible to run through the faction headquarters to the Human Resources Manager, but the faction change will not take effect properly until after you next change zone - meaning you'll likely die shortly after speaking to the Human Resources Manager for your new faction.